# Trying to deserialize and serialize a table in lua using the serpent library

Tags: serialization, lua, deserialization

So I am trying to do a simple serialization of a lua table, and deserialize it back into a table. But for some reason it just fails.

```
local a = {}
a[0] = {name="presetA"}
local line = serpent.line(a)

local presets, err = loadstring(line)

if (err) then
    log("Error")
    log(err)
else
    log("Success")
    log(serpent.block(presets))
end
```

After running, log(err) shows

```
[string "{[0] = {name = "presetA"}}"]:1: unexpected symbol near '{'
```

Comment: Replace `loadstring(line)` with `loadstring("return "..line)()`

Comment: It seems that there is a special function `serpent.load` for deserialization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

loadstring loads a Lua chunk from the given string and runs it.

As your serialized table is not a valid Lua expression the interpreter reports the observed error.

Let's serialze an example:

```
serpent.line({key = "value"})
```

returns

> "{key = "value"} --[[table: 0D80CF40]]"

A table constructor on it's own is not a valid Lua expression.

Try to run that line and you'll Lua will report:

> input:1: unexpected symbol near '{'

The output of serpent.line cannot be used as input to `loadstring`.

Now see the difference if you use `serpent.dump` instead

```
"do local _={name="hallo"};return _;end"
```

This is a valid, executable Lua chunk that will return the serialized table.

Please note the following section from the [serpent documentation](https://github.com/pkulchenko/serpent):

> **Note that line and block functions return pretty-printed data
>   structures and if you want to deserialize them, you need to add return
>   before running them through loadstring.** For example:
>   `loadstring('return '..require('mobdebug').line("foo"))() == "foo"`.
>
> While you can use loadstring or load functions to load serialized
>   fragments, Serpent also provides load function that adds safety checks
>   and reports an error if there is any executable code in the fragment...

Please read manuals.